# CodeIgniter backend site to extend to support frontend site

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently working on a CodeIgniter project which is currently using as the admin backend for a mobile API. On config.php, they have used a sub domain for base url; `$config['base_url'] = 'http://admin.website.com/';` and now they want to create a frontend website for their app.

1. what is the best way to create a frontend website for this project? I have to access the uploaded files on this for frontend site.
2. is there anyway to create a module for the frontend web site with existing admin project and can I redirect http://website.com to that module while using "admin.website.com" as the base_url?

Thanks

Comment: I would say, you need two CI application to achieve this. tow application with two different config and two index file which they are located in different locations. The Database should be shared between these two.

Comment: If you were interested, just notice me to send a full answer. I'm **NOT** interested in collecting reputation, but helping people.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but how to access the existing uploaded files on admin CI app from frontend CI app?

Comment: First you should clear what are the `files`. are they static files loke images, js or css files or they are dynamic php files like `views`? both of them would be accessible.

Comment: mostly image files, uploaded by admin for content which has been stored on /uploaded_files directory. What is the best way to access them from another CI project.

Comment: If the `uploaded_files` folder is somewhere outside of `application` or `system` folder (it should be! to be able to reach the files inside), it shouldn't be any problem. The backend app is an addon domain, by default it is located in `public_html/admin` folder. in frontend app, you can access files by `base_url('admin/uploaded_files/foo.bar');`. It is better to define a constant in frontend app `index.php` file and declare the backend admin folder as `ADMINPATH`. This makes refactoring code much easier.

Comment: Thanks for the help, hope to create a separate project for frontend with the limited time I got. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest this link for complete solition

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/07/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter

On this site 3 methods are given choose which fits your requirements

Comment: Thanks for the reply. we can usually create admin folder for backend controllers but currently on this app, they have used controllers for admin backend with 'admin.website.com' base_url. I want to create a frontend site for 'website.com'.